# Add VMSS to Backend Pool of Application gateway using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, devops, azure-cli

I have tried adding the VMSS to backend pool of application gateway using the following methods

1. Using az network application-gateway backend-pool add-servers

```
az network application-gateway address-pool update --resource-group "Resource group name" --gateway-name "Application Gateway name" --name "backend address pool name" --add backendAddresses "ip/fqdn"
```

The only way to make this work is using the IP address or FQDN of the instances, but I want to be able to add the entire VMSS to the backend(we can add the VMSS using the console to the backend but azure CLI documentation doesn't have anything about adding the entire VMSS).

Why am I looking for adding the entire VMSS? The instances might get rotated inside the VMSS and the ip/fqdn will change.
Why am I looking for CLI commands only? I am working on an automation script.

2. Updating the VMSS

```
az vmss update --resource-group "resource group name" --name "VMSS name" --set virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations."[0]".ipConfigurations."[0]".applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools."[]".id="Application Gateway backend address pool id"
```

Using this method I am getting the following error

```
Couldn't find '[]' in 'virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools'. 'virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].applicationGatewayBackendAddressPools' does not support further indexing.
```

Please suggest any alternative way or if you think I'm doing anything wrong please point that out?
I also contacted Azure Support and they said only way to add to backend address pool of application gateway is using ip address and fqdn.

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest using internal load balancer in front of VMSS and use the private ip address of the load balancer for app gateway backend pool.

Comment: Is there any other way you can think of? Adding an Internal Load Balancer in front my VMSS's would be a pain as I've many VMSS's, Thanks for your response.

Comment: just took a second look at your 2nd method. What if you try following --add construct: --add virtualMachineProfile.networkProfile.networkInterfaceConfigurations[0].ipConfigurations[0].ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools '{"id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/{applicationGatewayName}/backendAddressPools/{applicationGatewayBackendPoolName}"}'